# How to add Swing Components to another JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

Please help me to add   Swing Components like `JTable` to already created `JFrame` Form using Netbeans

Comment: Your question is not clear...

Comment: @MikeLaren  Since the OP mentioned *"using Netbeans by Drag and Drop method"* the [tag:netbeans] tag **is** relevant!

Comment: To add Swing Components like JTable to already created JFrame Form using Netbeans

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.setSize(300,300);
frame.setVisible(true);
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

JTable table = new JTable(5, 5);
table.setBackground(Color.GRAY);

frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
frame.add(table);
```

The last two lines are the key in adding a component to a JFrame. You need to set a Layout that the Swing would be following in adding the component to the frame, then add the component.